# Module instance methods on later defined class

Tags: ruby

I want to note that this is COMPLETELY a made up question. I am aware that there are other ways to accomplish this.

I want to declare a module like so

```
module Foo
 # some logic here to
 # get instance method 'foo' on
 # a later defined class
end
```

then later I want to declare a class like:

```
class Foo::Bar
end
```

Then WITHOUT using include or extend be able to do this:

```
Foo::Bar.new.foo
```

and have it call the foo method I defined in module Foo

Comment: You know that I Know, that you know, that you should have just listened to me in the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Foo
 class Bar
   def foo
     puts "erik is a dummy"
     end
   end
 end
Foo::Bar.new.foo
=> erik is a dummy
```

Comment: Erik and I are friends IRL... Lol!

Comment: More like frenemies - But i think he wants the class and module declaration to be separate.